# sql server 2008 table valued parameters linq2sql

Tags: linq-to-sql, sql-server-2008, table-valued-parameters

Has anybody experimented with these. Is this supported?

Answer (score 4):

Table Value parameters aren't supported yet in LINQ to SQL. There's a few posts about this on Microsoft's MSDN forums:

> [DbType.Structured not available](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/4d2957f6-9e3d-4396-9b3d-1c333245bd96/)
>
> [SQL Server 2k8.User Defined Table Type. Mapping between DbType 'Structured' and Type 'System.Object'](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/afdeec9a-5ffc-4f7e-a11a-ad34f4569db8)

The second link refers to Entity Framework, but the underlying issue is the same.

Answer (score 3):

I actually had to try this myself. :0

It does not seem to be supported. I get this error when adding a stored procedure using a tvp parameter into the dbml file

DBML1005: Mapping between DbType 'Structured' and Type 'System.Object' in Parameter 'TVP' of Function 'dbo.spTestTableTypeParm' is not supported

Sad but true, I thought this could be a killer feature of sql 2008 and linq2sql