# What pattern to follow when I manually open connection in DataContext

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, ado.net, table-valued-parameters

Linq2Sql does not support table-valued parameters for stored procedures ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338029/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters-linq2sql), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019414/linq-to-sql-with-stored-procedures-and-user-defined-table-type-parameter)).

Because of this, I'm adding an ugly support for table-valued parameters in my DataContext (just to keep things consistent and still be able to call my procedures from within the same data context).

I call `this.Connection.CreateCommand()`, cast it to `SqlCommand` (because it's going to be `SqlCommand` anyway to support the TVP), manually list all parameters including the `SqlDbType.Structured` ones, and `ExecuteNonQuery` it.

This works fine.
But.
Inside my helper method I have to open the context connection because it may be closed. **Because I manually open connection, do I have to manually close it?**

I've been through these:
[Do I have to close the SQL Connection manually if I use Linq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400866/do-i-have-to-close-the-sql-connection-manually-if-i-use-linq)
[When should I dispose of a data context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389822/when-should-i-dispose-of-a-data-context)
[When the connection to database starts if i use DataContext?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805210/when-the-connection-to-database-starts-if-i-use-datacontext)

but they don't actually answer my question. I understand the connection is closed when result are enumerated, but it's more complex than that. Calling a method is not a read-only operation, as opposed to enumerating results.
Besides, if there's an ambient transaction, `DataContext` will definitely not close the connection after the first method call:

```cs
using (var ambient_tran = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope())
{
    using (var dx = new SomeDataContext()) 
    {
        dx.CallMethodOne(foo, bar);
        dx.CallMethodTwo(bar, baz); // executed on same connection and same transaction,
                                    // can see uncommitted data entered by CallMethodOne
    }

    ambient_tran.Complete();
};
```

Because of all this, I'm not sure what is **the right thing** to do in regard of the connection.
**Am I just to open connection and leave `DataContext` manage its lifetime, or is there a pattern to follow?**

---

**EDIT:**

Experiments show that if I just leave it open, it behaves fine and automatically respects an ambient transaction, if any. However, I would prefer a solid advice on that.

Answer (score -1):

If you do not need distributed transactions, then avoid using System.Trasactions. Instead, see my [TextMetal](http://code.google.com/p/textmetal/) project, the sample code, and pay attention to the Plumbing namespace. If you have questions, email me. No MSDTC slight of hand, just proper generated ADO.NET/LINQ to SQL, a unit of work pattern, and some well engineered data access code!

If there is a compelling reason to use System.Transactions, then I advise you still close the connection as soon as possible as the transaction coordinator will manage the commit/rollback after the connection is released to the pool.